# Am I the only one who has issue with editing the Location in my profile section

Tags: bug, user-accounts, profile-page

Sorry, I am posting this in meta.exchange. I didn't find any other place regarding this issue.
Please refer the screenshot:

[image]

**Edit:** My Console says

[image]

Comment: I don't have this issue personally...

Comment: @Tally ... it is resolved for me also